# Method that writes list of strings to file works only the last time when it`s called

Tags: c#

I wrote function for writing list of strings to file
and I need to call it multiple times however it works only the last time when I call it

```
public static void WriteToFile(string UserText, List<string> ListToBeWritten, string Path)       
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(UserText);
            foreach (var lines in ListToBeWritten)
            {

                sw.WriteLine(lines);

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you create a new `StreamWriter` it will overwrite the contents of the file if it exists every time. If you just want to append to an existing file you could set the `append` parameter to true when instantiating the writer using [`this constructor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path, append: true))
```

Quote from the documentation:

> Initializes a new instance of the StreamWriter class for the specified
>   file by using the default encoding and buffer size. If the file
>   exists, it can be either overwritten or appended to. If the file does
>   not exist, this constructor creates a new file.